# Get place in table of icon using ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table that's generated using `ng-repeat` with some columns headers. On the column headers, I want to columns to be sorted. I included a `font-awesome` sort icon next to their text and when it's clicked, I call an `ng-click` with `ng-click="sortColumn()"`. I'm calling this for every column header.

How do I know which column header got clicked on? Right now it fires for each header column.

How do pass the current column in using `ng-click`?

I tried to pass in `this`, but it returns the `$scope` object.

Here's what I have so far:

`HTML:`

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Product </b><i class="fa fa-sort" ng-click="vm.sortColumn(this)"></i></td>
            <td><b>Code </b><i class="fa fa-sort" ng-click="vm.sortColumn(this)"></i></td>
            <td><B>Available </b><i class="fa fa-sort" ng-click="vm.sortColumn(this)"></i></td>
            <td><B>Price </b><i class="fa fa-sort" ng-click="vm.sortColumn(this)"></i></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{ vm.noProducts }}
        <tr ng-repeat="product in vm.products">
            <td>{{ product.productName}}</td>
            <td>{{ product.productCode }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.releaseDate | date }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.price | currency }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`Javascript:`

```
vm.sortColumn = function (obj) {
    console.log(obj);
}
```

Comment: can you pass directly the column name in the function like `vm.sortColumn(product)` if they column names are static?

Comment: @Niladri Yes I can, but I would have to check which column it was in the function. I would rather not produce more code. I'm looking for a more elegant approach for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can just pass column as object to sortColumn(). If you need column in that function you can loop trough products and make a new array that will be populated for example with all product names.
Maybe that function could look like this:

```
function getColumn(val){ // 'productName'
      var column = [];
      for(var i in $scope.products){
        column.push(column.push($scope.products[i][val]))
      }
      return column
 }
```

If you want to sort table you can use [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) filter.
To your sortColumn() function pass parameter name and in your ng-repeat use orderBy to order column ascending/descending by one of the parameters.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td ng-click="sortColumn('productName')"><b>Product </b></td>
            <td ng-click="sortColumn('productCode')"><b >Code </b></td>
            <td ng-click="sortColumn('releaseDate')"><b >Available </b></td>
            <td ng-click="sortColumn('price')"><b >Price </b></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy: criteria">
            <td>{{ product.productName}}</td>
            <td>{{ product.productCode }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.releaseDate | date }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.price | currency }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In your controller set default value for orderBy criteria. (I used here productName)

```
    $scope.criteria = 'productName';

    $scope.sortColumn = function(val){
      console.log(val)
      if($scope.criteria == val){
        $scope.criteria = "-"+val;
      } else {
        $scope.criteria = val;
      }
```

If user clicks on productCode for example, all rows will be sorted by that criteria ascending ('productCode'), if user click on productCode once again all will be sorted descending by criteria '-productCode'

I created small [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/l3RE5MtW0PpI87j1urhV?p=preview) to demonstrate that. Hope it helps.